# Depth-First-Search (Stack or Recursion?)

Tags: java, graph, stack, depth-first-search

For DFS, do you always have to use a Stack? After doing some research, I see some people implement recursion instead of Stack iteration, and it seems to yield the same result.

Is one more efficient than the other? Plenty of recursive algorithms employ a secondary or even sometimes tertiary helper methods that run recursively.

I'm asking as I have to employ DFS on a Graph, I've been trying to do recursion, I think I almost nailed it, but I'm being cautious for any errors.

Comment: Recursion also uses a stack - the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

I think, recursion is the more readable way to do a depth-first-search since your code execution is following the very idea you're implementing. On the other hand, recursion has certain risks since it uses the call stack which is a part of memory separate from where a stack data structure would be stored and it's limited in size. If your search is to deep, you'll trigger `StackOverflowError`s and a termintaed execution.

The depth limit is hard to tell because the amount of memory needed for each recursion step depends on the number and type of your recursive methods parameters and I think the size of the call stack varies betwenn different JVM vereions and vendors.

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, recursion seems to be the easier way to go, plus for my implementation I'm not actually using a stack, I'm just going to the next node in the graph, and then back-tracking, with an array of boolean values, that checks whether the node was visited.

Comment: If you're using recursion, you're using the call stack. It's the very definition of recursion in Java. In recursion you have a method calling itself. Translated to Java that says you have a method on the call stack putting itself on the call stack above itself.